# python scrape/get data aspx query

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from this site using python https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx

I read some explanations but I'm still confused about the request headers. What would be the python code to scrape the above site/search by a DOT# or company name.

Thank you.

Comment: That’s what I meant. I have a DOT number or a company name I want to lookup. How do I do that? I’m sorry if I have made my question not as clear as it should have. Again I’m not trying to scrape the database and obtain all the data from it. I have a specific DOT number or company name that I want to look up. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look into the website and found that there you can put 3 types of values i.e USDOT Number ,MC/MX Number ,Name using radio buttons.Name gives data in GET from like [https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/keywordx.asp?searchstring=%2A{name_search}%2A&SEARCHTYPE=ANY](https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/keywordx.asp?searchstring=%2A%7Bname_search%7D%2A&SEARCHTYPE=ANY) which you can easily get by requesting this url just by replacing {name_search} with your search name .

While USDOT and MC/MX are requesting in POST format form sending to https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp like searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param={USDOT/MC_MX}&query_string={your_number} for which you have to make a program for getting it for sending this data to the server.

```
import requests
url = 'https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp'
data = {'searchtype':'ANY','query_type':'queryCarrierSnapshot',
'query_param':'USDOT','query_string':'529136'}
r = requests.post(url = url,data = data)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: How do I write the program? That's what I'm interested in. The second option.

Comment: You can use requests package in python .Suppose You want USDOT number = 123456789 results.Your code can be as above edited:

Comment: also read the documentation and the article for more information.[Documentation link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/),[Article link](https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/view-post-data-using-chrome-developer-tools/)

Comment: I tried your code. Got an error: NameError: name 'query_string' is not defined" Please try this with DOT = "529136" as an example. It is a valid number and should return a result. Again, I'm completely unfamiliar with aspx that's why I'd like a template code that I could use. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I made some silly mistake in my code. Now the edited code is correct I ran it myself. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The site is a simple from fill up page. You cannot scrape the DOT# or company name from this page for security concern as the header will request your data from server by sending the input POST method.For really scraping the data you can do brute-force method or by using dictionary and send per predicted query to the server continuously for finding the right ones.

Comment: That’s what I meant. I have a DOT number or a company name I want to lookup. How do I do that? I’m sorry if I have made my question not as clear as it should have. Again I’m not trying to scrape the database and obtain all the data from it. I have a specific DOT number or company name that I want to look up. Can you help me with that?